# Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request in Instagram API creation of new client

Tags: magento, instagram

I am developing a magento site, I want to do instagram login in my website. I tried to create API in instagram but it displays  Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request. I have searched in google but did not get a solution to resolve it.

Don't know how to resolve this?
Can anyone guide me for creating an api in instagram?
Thanks in advance

Comment: No need of any authentication now https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having this issue today. After several hours of troubleshooting, I believe Instagram is having API issues.

I have tried setting up subscriptions using their /subscribe endpoint, which are currently working, and all are returning 'Unable to reach callback URL' as well.